# Condition '<>'&'ValueString' in SUMIFS -how it works

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to understand the SUMIFS formula, which looks like this:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A10; A1:A10; ">0"; B1:B10; "<>"&"Property")
```

Let's say, `B1:B10` contains values such as 'Property', "Town1", "Town2" and empty cells.
I don't understand what is the role of AND with the "not empty" condition ("<>") and specifying "Property" value?

Please, could someone explain how this formula works?
Wouldn't  specifying only  "Property" condition give the save result?

Comment: `&` this is not `AND()` function, it is `Ampersand` which is used to concatenate multiple values into one single continuous value. Also if you want to exclude empty then it should be like --> `=SUMIFS(A1:A10;A1:A10;">0";B1:B10;"<>")`

Comment: If you want to exclude any specific then it should be like `=SUMIFS(A1:A10;A1:A10;">0";B1:B10;"<>Town1")` which excludes `Town1` better to use a cell reference for the criteria. Or use `=SUMIFS(A1:A10;A1:A10;">0";B1:B10;"<>Property")`

Comment: This is not my formula, it is in the document which I am trying to understand. So what would be the result then?

Comment: The result will output with the summation of those values which are greater than `0` and not equal to `Property`

Comment: I see, thank you.
They couldn't write "<>Property" because it is a string?

Comment: Why what error do you get? Then use a cell reference. --> `=SUMIFS(A1:A10;A1:A10;">0";B1:B10;"<>"&C1)` where `C1=Property`

Comment: Ah, I didn't read your previous comment thoroughly. It looks like someone just used some unnesessary syntaxis?
They could use "<>Property" instead of "<>"&"Property" and it would be ok?

Comment: As they wish. Both works by the way! `"<>Property"` or `"<>"&"Property"`

Comment: Yes. I assume whoever wrote this was used to using it with a cell reference like `"<>"&A1` where it makes sense this way since the contents of `A1` won't be known in advance.